# Install DLC package for an Adobe AIR app

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have an existing AIR app installed on many machines (only PC and Mac for now). Currently the filesize of this app is pretty big. It contains a lot of images and video. I was wondering if it was possible to provide a "DLC update" type of installer, that just contains a few more media assets that could be installed into the existing AIR apps install directory.

I have written my AIR app to detect all the media in a subfolder, so just need to get the new content in there. I don't really want to provide a new installer that includes all the assets they already have installed.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do, is update your existing app to be aware of what it should have within the media folder, rather than blindly finding what is already there. Create a manifest file that defines all the files that should be there. Include not only the file name for each, but also a download URL/path it can be retrieved from. Check for each one, building a queue of files it needs to download, then fetch the files you need and write them out.

Comment: Ok, so your suggestion is to just download the content from an online source, rather than giving a package that installed just the new content? I was hoping I wouldn't need internet access for this. Just provide an update package on a USB stick. But that would be a good solution if internet access was available.

Comment: Well, your question gave no parameters about internet connection. If you are just going to go around with a USB stick, then just drag/drop the files into the media folder.